# How to write an image in Pdf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have to write text and images in a pdf using Flex, but the image does not appear. Can you see what the error is? Here is my code:

```
...

private var image:Loader = new Loader;
private var pdf:PDF;

protected function onBtnGeneratePDF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
pdf = new PDF( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4 );
pdf.setDisplayMode( Display.FULL_PAGE, Layout.SINGLE_PAGE );

var newPage:Page = new Page ( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4 );
pdf.addPage( newPage );

image.load(new URLRequest("bear.jpg"));
image.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.CO MPLETE, done);

var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("testPdf.pdf"); 
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); 
var bytes:ByteArray = pdf.save(Method.LOCAL); 
fs.writeBytes(bytes); 
fs.close();
}

private function done (e:Event):void {
pdf.addImage(image, null, 20, 20);
}

]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button x="10" y="179" label="Generate PDF" click="onBtnGeneratePDF(event)"/>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not working but you can also check AlivePDF, an ActionScript3 PDF library. Have a look in this [tutorial](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/?page_id=5) and also this [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2008/11/03/generate-pdfs-from-your-flash-flex-and-air-apps/).